# Trocando o template_name em TemplateView (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views

Como eu faço para trocar o template_name em TemplateView se o usuário estiver autenticado?

Vejam o que eu tentei

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    # template_name = 'index.html'

    is_auth = False

    def get(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.is_auth = True
            return HttpResponse('Não')

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.is_auth:
            return ['%s.html' % self.kwargs['template']]
        # else:
            # return '/crm/employee/add/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom cara, se você tem uma visão diferente para uma pessoa autenticada e uma que não esteja autenticada, estude a possibilidade de deixar uma view para cada coisa. Caso o tratamento de informações aumente, isso evitará gambiarras.

Mas respondendo sua dúvida:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return ['template_logado.html']
        else:
            return ['template_publico.html']
```